# Unable to set nested object value in vuex state completely

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I have data in database with nested object like:

```
[{"id":"1-368","name":"\tSolan","days":1,"daynights":2,"hotel":{"hotel_data":[{"id":1,"title":"hotel 1"}],"checkin":"","checkout":"","roomtype":""},"hotel2":{"hotel_data":[{"id":1,"title":"hotel 1"}],"checkin":"","checkout":"","roomtype":""},"specinst":"","mealplan":""},{"id":"2-54","name":"Dharamsala","days":"3","daynights":4,"hotel":{"hotel_data":[{"id":3,"title":"hotel3"}],"checkin":"","checkout":"","roomtype":""},"hotel2":{"hotel_data":[{"id":2,"title":"hotel 2"}],"checkin":"","checkout":"","roomtype":""},"specinst":"","mealplan":""}]
```

Now when I am trying to fetch data and try to assign to a state through mutation it get assigned incompletely like:

```
[{"id":"1-368","name":"\tSolan","days":1,"daynights":2,"hotel":{"hotel_data":"","checkin":"","checkout":"","roomtype":""},"hotel2":{"hotel_data":"","checkin":"","checkout":"","roomtype":""},"specinst":"","mealplan":"","date_from":"08 Jan 2020","date_to":"09 Jan 2020"},{"id":"2-54","name":"Dharamsala","days":"3","daynights":4,"hotel":{"hotel_data":"","checkin":"","checkout":"","roomtype":""},"hotel2":{"hotel_data":"","checkin":"","checkout":"","roomtype":""},"specinst":"","mealplan":"","date_from":"09 Jan 2020","date_to":"12 Jan 2020"}]
```

In above code you can notice `hotel_data` is a nested array but not able see after assigning it to `vuex` state.

code:

```
const mutations = {
setItem(state, item) {


    state.item.tour_location=JSON.parse(item.tour_location);
 }}
```

Comment: In what format is the data being returned by the server? Is it a JSON string or just a normal array?

Answer (score 0):

What do you see if you `console.log(item.tour_location);` within the `setItem` mutation? If the data is coming in with the correct structure, I would recommend setting up your state as a skeleton of the expected data. 
For example:
Expected data: `{id: 'abc', hotel: [{ prop1: '123', prop2: '234']}`
Vuex state: `{id: '', hotel: [{ prop1: '', prop2: '' }]}`

Hope this helps.

Comment: My data structure is dynamic that's why I dont know no. of array nodes that will be created at hotel node.

Comment: From the code that your provided, will `hotel.hotel_data` always be an array (regardless of the # of elements)? If yes, set it in state like so: `{ hotel: { hotel_data: [], ...other_props } }`